# listview loading image react native android

Tags: react-native

I have a problem. I have a listview. I want to add loading image while wait show image in screen.
I've been tried react-native-fast-image, react-native-image-progress. But not.
You can help me. thankssss.

Index.js

```
     <ListView
      enableEmptySections
      style={styles.list}
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={rowData => <ArtStreamRow artwork={rowData} />}
      scrollRenderAheadDistance={3000}
      initialListSize={30}
      onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
      onEndReachedThreshold={900}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={this.props.isRefreshing}
          onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
        />
```

ArtStreamRow.js

```
class ArtStreamRow extends PureComponent {
 render() {
const {
  artwork,
} = this.props;

 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TouchableNativeFeedback
      onPress={viewArtworkDetail.bind(this, artwork)}
      background={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 
            TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackground() : ''}
    >
      <Image
        source={{ uri: getUrl(artwork) }}
        style={styles.artworkImage}
        resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.cover}
      />
    </TouchableNativeFeedback>
  </View>
    )
  }
```

here, loading image, I want to add.
[image: image loading]